Is it possible to do tail recursion with tasks?
Is it possible to do tail recursion with methods returning tasks?
The following example does not create a correct tail recursion function:
[<TailCall>]
let rec isThisPossible () =
    task {
        // Do some stuff with tasks here ...
        // Warning: FS3569
        return! isThisPossible()
    }

When I replace task with async the Compiler warning goes away and I can run my example without a stack overflow.

The syntax of F# computation expressions is syntactic sugar which, once desugared, calls methods of the associated builder class (.Bind, .Return, .ReturnFrom, ...). As such, tail-calls are not possible, at least I don't think so. Actually, this might depends on the implementation of computation expression.

@Foxy But async seems to work. Is it a special implementation?

The simple answer to your question is, no, not yet.
Async was implemented >14y ago and first class support for tail recursion is a non-negotiable core feature. The task builder was introduced in F# 6 and tail recursion is explicitly not yet supported. There are language discussions in various stages covering a) rebuilding async to work off the mechanisms tha underpin task b) filling the gaps in what task can't do well that async can e.g. tail recursion, but also other pieces

@RubenBartelink Thank you for your answer. I extracted my task related stuff into a function and called it with Async.AwaitTask in an Async Tail Recursion Function.

Yes, in principle that should be a decent workaround (give or take Async.AwaitTask doing wacky wrapping https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/840)

As discussed in the comments here is a possible solution with a recursive async function and a separate task function:
let taskFunction param : Task =
    task {
        // Do your task stuff here
        return! Task.CompletedTask
    }

[<TailCall>]
let rec recursiveAsyncFunction param =
    async {
        do! taskFunction param |> Async.AwaitTask
        return! recursiveAsyncFunction param
    }

